# BigQuery remove duplicate column names when joining on FULL JOIN + USING

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two BigQuery tables that have exactly the same column names, that need to be joined together, while preserving the correct names for the stats. In my actual example, my tables are named `offensive` and `defensive`, and they contain offensive and defensive basketball statistics for teams. The column names in both tables are:

```
team, game, fga, fgm, ast, blk, stk
```

I want to join the columns on the columns `team` and `game`. I found [the following example](https://copycoding.com/d/rename-all-column-names-for-joining-purpose-in-big-query), which looks perfect for my use case, however one thing I do not like is that the example doens't remove the duplicate joined-on columns (company, vendor, transaction in the example). After joining, I don't want 2 of `team` and `game` in my table. I tried:

```
SELECT offensive, defensive EXCEPT (team, game)
FROM offensive FULL JOIN defensive
USING (team, game)
```

...and am receiving the following `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword EXCEPT at [40:39]` error. Any thoughts on how to remove the duplicate joined-on columns would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT team, game, 
  (SELECT AS STRUCT offensive.*  EXCEPT (team, game)) AS offensive,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT defensive.*  EXCEPT (team, game)) AS defensive
FROM offensive FULL JOIN defensive
USING (team, game)
```

this will result in below schema

```
team game offensive.fga offensive.fgm offensive.ast offensive.blk offensive.stk defensive.fga defensive.fgm defensive.ast defensive.blk defensive.stk
```

something like

```
[
  {
    "team": "1",
    "game": "1",
    "offensive": {
      "fga": "1",
      "fgm": "2",
      "ast": "3",
      "blk": "4",
      "stk": "5"
    },
    "defensive": {
      "fga": "21",
      "fgm": "22",
      "ast": "23",
      "blk": "24",
      "stk": "25"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you. If I may ask, what is the `AS STRUCT` function doing here that makes this operation work whereas mine did not?

Comment: meantime, AS STRUCT "combines" list of output columns into one struct column (RECORD)

Comment: For sure, will do. Honestly the BQ support has been too good sometimes in that I get an answer before I'm even able to accept it, and then I do not remember to come back to it.